# Connection with neo4j-client failed on OS X yosemite

Tags: c++, neo4j-dotnet-driver

I've tried to establish a connection by both command line and in my C++ project. 
In a "secure" version I received:

`OpenSSL error: 336130315:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number`

If I try with an insecure connection, I received:

`connection to 'neo4j://localhost:7474' failed: Could not agree on a protocol version`

but I successfully access to the db via browser on the same port number.
How could I repair?
An insecure connection is good for me.

Comment: Port numbers are different. The browser uses 7474, while via code you have to use 7687

Comment: Are you using the official `neo4j-driver` for this?

Comment: yes. I solved by changing the port. Thanks

Comment: OK great, I'll just change the tags so you get help from the right people!